# wordpress subfolder url htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to create folder on my site which is named demo

so www.mysite.com/demo/afile.html

but i want it so it looks like demo.mysite.com/afile.html

i have edited the htaccess file that was already created by wordpress

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^demo\.mysite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/demo/
RewriteRule (.*) /demo/$1

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

But when i go to demo.mysite.com/afile.html its not found. What am i doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to create the subdomain demo.mysite.com that point to a folder with a .htaccess on it.

But in this case, you just have to choose the directory containing your demo site /path/to/mysite/demo as the DocumentRoot for the subdomain demo.mysite.com (and no need for rewrite rules)

Comment: im still a little confused, so do i not need too add htaccess with a sub domain?